# htaccess redirect folder but not subfolder of same name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a new web-site and that is listed as www.example.com/newFolder.

I want to redirect all traffic going to www.example.com/oldFolder... to newFolder.
But I still want access to www.example.com/old_root/oldFolder

I tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldFolder(.*)$ /newFolder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldFolder[/]?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old_root/oldFolder[/]?
RewriteRule (.*) /newFolder [R=301,L]
```

but both also redirect /old_root/oldFolder.

Comment: `RedirectMatch` is fine, test in a new browser.

Comment: Darn, just had to close the browser and reopen.